# how to know the array index of particular value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array coming from database:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [cSize] => 120x60 
        [cFilename] => 29955_120x60.png 
        [dtLastUpdated] => 2017-06-11T18:18:34-07:00 
        [cURL] => http://logos.formetocoupon.com/120x60/29955.png 
    ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [cSize] => 280x210 
        [cFilename] => 29955_280x210.png 
        [dtLastUpdated] => 2017-08-15T23:31:05-07:00 
        [cURL] => http://logos.formetocoupon.com/280x210/29955.png 
    ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( 
        [cSize] => 600x450 
        [cFilename] => 29955_600x450.png 
        [dtLastUpdated] => 2017-08-15T23:31:05-07:00 
        [cURL] => http://logos.formetocoupon.com/600x450/29955.png 
    ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( 
        [cSize] => 88x31 
        [cFilename] => 29955_88x31.png 
        [dtLastUpdated] => 2017-06-11T18:18:34-07:00 
        [cURL] => http://logos.formetocoupon.com/88x31/29955.png 
    ) 
)
```

I want to know the index of the array which contains the image size `120x60`.

I did this

```
$data=json_decode($value->aLogos);
$searchValue="120x60";
if (($key = array_search($searchValue, $data)) !== false) {
   print_r($key);
}
```

But it is printing nothing. How can I solve this issue? Any kind of suggestion are highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your first issue is that you're not searching an array of arrays but an array of objects.

Your second issue is that even if it was an array of arrays, `array_search` doesn't do multi-dimensional arrays.

Instead consider something like this in raw PHP:

```
$data = json_decode($value->aLogos);
$searchValue="120x60";
foreach($data as $key => $obj) {
    if ($searchValue == $obj->cSize) {
        break;
    }
}
echo $key; //holds key of first object with desired value
```

Alternatively, check out the `array_search_deep` method here: http://brandonwamboldt.github.io/utilphp/#array_search_deep

Comment: the key name is unknown beforehand

Comment: Not how I interpret the question but if that's the case `array_search_deep()` can handle that no problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do roughly somthing like this using the [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) function

```
foreach ($data as $value){
   if ($value->cSize=="120x60"){
       echo key($data);
}
```

Comment: the key name is unknown beforehand

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, key is a function takes and array and return the actual index

Comment: you didn't get it: `cSize` is unknown conceptionally

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I'm not sure what you're asking, but It loops through array values and when it finds a matching value it returns the index